# How to save a user's IP address to JavaScript variables when using webRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am attempting to save a user’s local IP address to a variable in JavaScript. I found part of the solution in a post by [mido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074768/mido) in an earlier question titled [How to get client’s IP address using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only/32841164#32841164). The solution works well and uses WebRTC with JavaScript to display the local IP; however, I have been unable to pass these IP addresses to a variable. The code below shows what I am trying to do.

In it, I have created an html tag with id=saveIP. I am trying to replace its contents with the user's IP (IPv4 for the moment). I created a varialbe window.saveIP for this purpose, and I'm using the document.getElementById('saveIP').innerHTML method towards the bottom of the script to pass the value to my HTML tag.

I have seen other solutions, but they all appear to simply display the IP address without saving them.

My question is what modifications must I make to capture the user's local IP(s) and save it to a variable?

```
<html>
<body>

 <p id=saveIP> Replace this with IP </p>

<script>

function findIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
  var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for firefox and chrome
  var pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers: []}),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;
    //window.saveIP = pc;
    //window.saveIP = localIPs; // Returns [object, object] or JSON.stringfy returns {}

  function ipIterate(ip) {
    if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
    localIPs[ip] = true;  
  }
  pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel
  pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
    sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
      if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
      line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
});
    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
  }, noop); // create offer and set local description
  pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) { //listen for candidate events
    if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
  };
}


var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.textContent = 'Your IPs are: '
document.body.appendChild(ul);

function addIP(ip) {
  console.log('got ip: ', ip);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = ip;
  window.saveIP = ip;  // <--value captured is [object HTMLParagraph]; JSON.stringify returns {}
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

findIP(addIP);
document.getElementById('saveIP').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(window.saveIP);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this call:

```
findIP(addIP);
```

is asynchronous, you are trying to set the result synchronously... move value assigning line inside `addIP` method.

---

**Update**:

try this min version:

```js
var findIP = new Promise(r=>{var w=window,a=new (w.RTCPeerConnection||w.mozRTCPeerConnection||w.webkitRTCPeerConnection)({iceServers:[]}),b=()=>{};a.createDataChannel("");a.createOffer(c=>a.setLocalDescription(c,b,b),b);a.onicecandidate=c=>{try{c.candidate.candidate.match(/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g).forEach(r)}catch(e){}}})

findIP.then(ip => document.getElementById('saveIP').innerHTML = ip).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

```html
<html>
<body>

 <p id=saveIP> Replace this with IP </p>
```

Comment: I thought I was doing that on line 45, window.saveIP = ip.

Comment: @Jacob put this line also inside: `document.getElementById('saveIP').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(window.saveIP);`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I clicked to give your answer an up vote, but I don't yet have the reputation points required for it to take affect. It didn't occur to me to place the document.getElementById('saveIP').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(window.saveIP); In my limited use of JavaScript, I haven't executed any asynchronous code, so I've been leaving it outside my functions. I'll post my completed solution once I have it all working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mido for pointing out the incorrect placement of my `document.getElementByID('saveIP').innerHTML =`

In order to capture both IPs, I included a counter and an if statement. The completed solution follows below.

```html
<html>
<body>

<p> You're IP's are: </p>
<p>
Local IP (IPv4): <text id=saveIP> Replace this with IP </text>
<br>
Local IP (IPv6): <text id=saveIP2> Replace this with IP </text>
</p>

<script>
var count = 0
function findIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
  var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for firefox and chrome
  var pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers: []}),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

  function ipIterate(ip) {
    if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
    localIPs[ip] = true;  
  }
  pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel
  pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
    sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
      if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
      line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
    });
    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
  }, noop); // create offer and set local description
  pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) { //listen for candidate events
    if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
  };
}

function addIP(ip) {
  console.log('got ip: ', ip);
  window.saveIP = ip;  // <--value captured is [object HTMLParagraph]; JSON.stringify returns {}
  if (count == 0){
  document.getElementById('saveIP').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(window.saveIP);  
  } else {document.getElementById('saveIP2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(window.saveIP); 
  }
  count = count+1
}

findIP(addIP);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```